# Post request to server is giving me error in express net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I want to collect the data from a simple HTML form and send it to the server. Unfortunately, I am making some mistakes and the server is not receiving the data.
The error in the console

> POST http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Here is my code.

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middleware
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "./public/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log('kkk', req.body);
});

var server = app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + PORT);
});
```

I am using `XMLHttpRequest()` to collect the data and here is the code.

```
const contactForm = document.querySelector('#contactForm');
let fullName = document.getElementById('fullName');
let email = document.getElementById('emailAddress');
let phone = document.getElementById('phoneNumber');
let message = document.getElementById('message');

contactForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = {
        name: fullName.value,
        email: email.value,
        phone: phone.value,
        message: message.value
    }
    
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open('POST', '/');
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    xhttp.onload = function() {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        if(xhttp.responseText == 'success') {
            console.log('Email sent successfully');
            fullName.value = '';
            emai.value = '';
            phone.value = '';
            message.value = '';
        }else {
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    }
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
});
```

If you want to check it live.

https://contact2021.herokuapp.com/

On Server, I can see the response

[image]

Comment: how are you starting your server?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong based on the code you provided. I know it's not exactly the same, but have you considered trying the fetch API instead? If nothing else, it would be helpful to try it instead of XMLHttpRequest to help pinpoint if it's a client-side or server-side issue. And from there you can focus your debugging efforts based on that.

Comment: I start the server from server.js using nodemon and it is deployed on heroku

Comment: The fetch given me Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Add debug print statements to both the client and server side just after the request is sent; if the request never reaches the server then you know the problem is on the client, in the same case if the server receives the request then you know the error is on the server.

Comment: The server is receiving the response because I can see it in the console. I edited the question plz check

Comment: Why are you using xmlhttp? wouldn't be simplier even with the built-in fetch api?

Comment: Also, the server `sends` the response and `receives` the request

Answer (score 1):

Testing your live site, I see that it hangs when posting to `https://contact2021.herokuapp.com/`. Presuming that this route is defined by the following:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log('kkk', req.body);
});
```

an issue is that you will need to initiate some kind of response, using one of the methods on [`Response`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) (eg [`res.end()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end), [`res.send()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send)).

This is likely not the same issue as the connection to `localhost:3000`, but if you are trying to access the site from any machine other that the one hosting it in development, then that connection wouldn't work, as it would be trying to connect to itself at that port.

Comment: I added your solution but not working

Comment: my full code is here https://github.com/ziaongit/sendemail

Comment: @ZiaUllahZia you're going to have to explain what not working means at this point; you've got at least two hosting environments (one local at `localhost:3000` and one on Heroku) and two issues (not being able to connect, and the POST timing out).

Comment: I have a form on the home page and want to link it to the node server. Both in localhost and Heroku I am receiving the same error

Comment: @ZiaUllahZia, currently a) posting from https://contact2021.herokuapp.com/#contact times out which implies the code there either doesn't have or isn't reaching the `res.end()` line b) running your code locally neither times out nor has an connection error. It fails due to the credentials not being correct, but commenting that out leaving only the `res.end()` causes the post to return immediately with a 200. If you are still receiving the connection error, and you are attempting access from the hosting machine locally, then you'll need to do the network dance, checking the firewall, etc.